# Sort array of dictionaries based on an order of array string

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an array of dictionary like:

```
    "account": [{
        "accountNo": "32211",
        "accountType": "01",
    }, {
        "accountNo": "12233",
        "accountType": "01",
    }, {
        "accountNo": "22244",
        "accountType": "01",
    }]
```

And I would like to sort it by comparing the accountNo on this orderList array:

```
["12233","22244"","11111","32211","44444"]
```

The sorted array of dictionary should look like this:

```
    "account": [{
        "accountNo": "12233",
        "accountType": "01",
    }, {
        "accountNo": "22244",
        "accountType": "01",
    }, {
        "accountNo": "32211",
        "accountType": "01",
    }]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Dictionary` is,

```
let dict = [
    "account": [
        [
            "accountNo": "32211",
            "accountType": "01",
        ], [
            "accountNo": "12233",
            "accountType": "01",
        ], [
            "accountNo": "22244",
            "accountType": "01",
        ]
    ]
]
```

and the `order` is

```
let order = ["12233","22244","11111","32211","44444"]
```

You can sort the `accounts` `Array` like,

```
if let accounts = dict["account"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    let sortedAccounts = accounts.sorted {
        if let n1 = $0["accountNo"] as? String, let n2 = $1["accountNo"] as? String, let index1 = order.firstIndex(of: n1), let index2 = order.firstIndex(of: n2) {
            return index1 < index2
        }
        return false
    }
    print(sortedAccounts)
}
```